# CORS - example of pre flight response headers where 'Origin' is not allowed

Tags: cors

I'm testing `CORS` support which has been recently added on one of the internal products (a web services gateway) at my company. The positive cases work fine and I'm able to see correct values for the following headers as shown (values of some headers is blanked intentionally):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, authorization  
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:[POST, GET]  
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ....  
Content-Length:0  
Date:Wed, 25 Sep 2013 18:49:31 GMT  
Server: ....
```

But my question is regarding expected response when the domain is NOT allowed:

- What should be the value of the above headers?
- Should response code always be a 200?
- What is the algorithm that the browser uses to determine if the pre-flight response has failed and it should NOT let the original call go through, is it consistent among browsers?

Comment: It's very simple: if the response does not acknowledge the origin, method, and non-simple headers, or if the response status is not 200, the preflight is considered a failure and the underlying request is not sent.  You can read more detail in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the requested permission is not to be allowed by your CORS policy then the way to indicate this is to omit the value(s) or the response header. Of course, if your server knows nothing of CORS (or OPTIONS) for the URL being requested, then you can also return a 404 or 405 status code which would tell the browser the cross-origin call is not allowed.

Comment: Is this mentioned that way in the specs? I see a lot of info on how positive responses should be but don't seem to find 'standard' or 'recommended' error response in the specs or some other credible source. Pl let me know if I'm missing it. Thanks..

Comment: Yes, the way the spec reads if that if you don't allow something then you "stop processing" in your HTTP server. This means you omit the response headers to say you don't allow something. This is the same behavior a server that doesn't know about CORS would exhibit.